# Code block evaluated when exporting, not when publishing

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, html, org-publish

I have this basic org publishing project to test that code blocks evaluation is triggered by publishing in html (org-html-publish-to-html).
While exporting through org-mode export dispatcher does evaluate code blocks automatically, publishing does not.

Here the content of the only file of the project, test.org:

```
#+NAME: ls
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :export results

echo $(ls)

#+END_src

#+RESULTS: ls
```

I publish the website running:

```
emacs --batch --no-init-file --load publish.el --funcall org-publish-all
```

with this `publish.el`:

```
(package-initialize)
;(require 'org)
(require 'ob-tangle)
(require 'ox-publish)
(require 'ox-latex)
(require 'ox-html)


(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil) ; don't ask for confirmation before evaluating a code block
(setq org-export-babel-evaluate t)
(setq org-export-use-babel t)


(setq org-publish-project-alist
      `(("test"
         :recursive t
         :base-directory "."
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "./public"
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :section-numbers nil
         )

        ))
```

(I also tried :`results html` and `:results output` with no more luck)

This is a toy test because I ran into the problem while building a website. I didn't see anywhere that publishing would not evaluate code, anyone has any info on that ?

It has been seen locally on my laptop as well as on a distant gitlab repo, the publishing process being ran on the distant git server.

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 / Org mode version 9.0.3 / Debian Jessie

Comment: My mistake, the header of the code block is actually: #+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results (exports, with an 's')
and it does not evaluate neither

Answer (score 2):

Finally works, seems the trick was to add:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 'org-babel-load-languages                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 '((sh . t)))
```

in publish.el